# Use pgrep command in an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I need to have a .sh file that will echo 0 if my python service is not running. I know that `pgrep` is the command I want to use, but I am getting errors using it.

```
if [ [ ! $(pgrep -f service.py) ] ]; then
    echo 0
fi
```

Is what I found online, and I keep getting the error

```
./test_if_running.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./test_if_running.sh: line 3: `fi;'
```

When I type

```
./test_if_running.sh
```

Comment: plz show us your top line. is it: #!bin/bash    ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit simple, but why not just print a *NOT*'d exit code, like so:

```
! pgrep -f service.py &> /dev/null ; echo $?
```

As a bonus it'll print `1` if the service *is* running.

Comment: When I do this, it prints a bunch of numbers, and then 1. Is there a way I can remove the numbers?

Comment: @ZachMozel, Yes, see revised answer.

Answer (score 6):

The issue in your code is the nested `[ ... ]`.  Also, as @agc has noted, what we need to check here is the exit code of `pgrep` and not its output.  So, the right way to write the `if` is:

```
if ! pgrep -f service.py &> /dev/null 2>&1; then
  # service.py is not running
fi
```